# Не запускается отладка приложения в android studio

Tags: android, android-sdk, android-studio

Когда пытаюсь запустить приложение на симуляторе, (в качестве симулятора использую реальный телефон соединенный через usb), то андроид студио выдает следующее:

```
  Uploading file
local path: C:\Users\ilnarL\AndroidStudioProjects\Gai.net\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.salamat.gainet 
Local path doesn't exist.
```

Кто нибудь знает как решить проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое видел, когда изменили .gradle файл и не сделали синхронизацию и в момент сборки система инвалидирует apk. Решение - сделать Sync в окне gradle.

Answer (score 2):

Пишет, что путь невыполнимый. Залейте файл в телефон и так запустите.

Answer (score 1):

Всем спасибо за ответы. В свое время я подключил к приложению библиотеку guava, так ей и не воспользовался, сейчас удалил перестроил gradle и все заработало

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]